# The economic impact of corruption

Tags: reference-request

I know nothing about the 'economics of corruption' literature, whether in the medium(fluctuations) or long-run(growth)... Although I've found many surveys (mostly +5 years, and from journals I don't recognize), since I known nothing about this subject, I have no idea with which ones I should start,.

I'm looking for two pointers

1. One to a survey/literature review from a well-established journal (QJE, etc.)
2. A book on this subject, but similar in difficulty to those books for the general public like "Nudge", "Irrational Exuberance", "Trade Talks", "The Triumph of Injustice", etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

A very nice survey from a now well-established journal is

- Olken, Benjamin A., and Rohini Pande. "Corruption in developing countries." Annual Review of Economics 4, no. 1 (2012): 479-509. Here is the [ungated NBER version](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w17398/w17398.pdf).
  It is not new and focuses on developing countries, but it is very influential. They try to answer three questions:

1. what is the degree of corruption?
2. What are the consequences of corruption in terms of efficiency?
3. and what determines the level of corruption?

Answer (score 2):

Olken and Pande (2012) is a great survey, but there are more resources.

Since you mention the long-term effects of corruption, here are some from the growth literature:

1. This is the first theoretical model on corruption and growth:
   Ehrlich, Isaac, and Francis T. Lui. "Bureaucratic corruption and endogenous economic growth." Journal of Political Economy 107, no. S6 (1999): S270-S293.
2. A paper on education and corruption in a growth model:
   Eicher, Theo, Cecilia García-Peñalosa, and Tanguy Van Ypersele. "Education, corruption, and the distribution of income." Journal of Economic Growth 14, no. 3 (2009): 205-231.
3. This includes collusion in corrupt activities in a growth model:
   Blackburn, Keith, Niloy Bose, and M. Emranul Haque. "The incidence and persistence of corruption in economic development." Journal of Economic Dynamics and control 30, no. 12 (2006): 2447-2467.
4. Not particularly a growth model, but they looked at the effect on average corruption over a period of time:
   Glaeser, Edward L., and Raven E. Saks. "Corruption in america." Journal of Public Economics 90, no. 6-7 (2006): 1053-1072.

Since you ask about books, here are two classics:

1. Rose-Ackerman, Susan. Corruption: A study in political economy. Academic Press, 2013.
2. Rose-Ackerman, Susan, and Bonnie J. Palifka. Corruption and government: Causes, consequences, and reform. Cambridge university press, 2016.

I notice this is an old question, so perhaps you already know about these sources.

Comment: Hi Erik, although it's an old question, I didn't know any of your sources. Many thanks ;)

Comment: :) There are more papers in the Economics of Corruption literature. Perhaps others (or you) will want to add some more of them.